# how to track submission of forms?

Tags: python, django, database, python-3.x, django-forms

I am relatively new to Django. I have multiple forms available in my application. I  have created those forms and the forms are getting processed successfully. Now I want a functionality that when user logs in, he/she sees a table or list of forms that he/she submitted. Like keeping a track of forms that user submitted. The data could look something like this:

```
|------------|----------------|----------------|-----------|------------|
| Project ID | Type           | date submitted | Requester | Staus      | 
|------------|----------------|----------------|-----------|------------|
| 1          | Seminar speaker| 07/25/2018     | Amey .    | In process | 
|------------|----------------|----------------|-----------|------------|
```

Can someone please suggest me a starting point or a blog that I can refer to tackle this functionality?

Or is there any library available in Django or compatible with Django that I can use to achieve my functionality?

Any Advise or help is appreciated?
As of now I am not pasting any code, but in case you need any I would be more than happy to share that piece of code.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/  Do some research on how to query data from the database you saved to.

Comment: This question is too broad. You can do it in many ways! Just create a database to store the forms submitted, and display it with a view!

Comment: @nosklo I believe you haven't read my question properly. I know my question is too board. That's the reason I am asking for an approach or a starting point and not solution. In case you have down-voted, please change it

Comment: I didn't downvote, I voted to close it. Stackoverflow is not for opinion-based questions - this question as written is offtopic here and should be closed @AmeyKelekar

Comment: @dfundako i did my research, definitely i know how to query database and view already submitted data and i am doing that in my application. My question is there any framework or library available using which I can achieve my functionality or I have go through a step by step process to achieve my functionality. I request you to change your downvote

Comment: you can use django-forms-builder. I think it would do the task for you. You can check it out here - https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-forms-builder

Comment: thanks @KrushiRaj for sharing the link. The link was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I didn't found a framework or module that helped me to achieve my functionality, I followed the approach shared by @nosklo and created a database to store the forms submitted, and display it with a view!